# How to insert data into the local database(table)

Tags: sql, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

On the older versions of VS it is quite simple to insert data into table database(without coding). But how to do this in 2017 VS?
https://i.stack.imgur.com/XJJMg.jpg

Comment: In the exact same way. Using Server Explorer, or SQL Server Object Explorer

Comment: Oh I found my mistake.. Anyways thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can still do the same with VS2017 with server explorer.